# ping and traceroute does not work when UFW deny outgoing by default

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

How to make ping and traceroute work after setting UFW with `deny outgoing` by default?

Here is my UFW configuration:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
123/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
123/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
587/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
123/udp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
587/tcp (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
123/udp (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Here are ping and traceroute results:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.121.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.121.34), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Operation not permitted
```

I found this post (http://www.kelvinism.com/2010/09/enable-icmp-through-ufw_461.html) that recommends to add these lines to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
# allow outbound icmp
-A ufw-before-output -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It seems to work for ping but not for traceroute. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
ufw allow out to any port 33434:33524 proto udp
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use sudo for `traceroute` and the `-I` option (`Use ICMP ECHO for tracerouting`):

```
sudo traceroute google.com -I
```

Answer (score 1):

For traceroute you need to allow outgoing UDP packets in the range 33434:33524.  Some tools will allow you to use ICMP echo requests as well.  As you have PING working, you must have enabled ICMP echo-requests packets.

Return packets will be mostly ICMP time-exceeded packets.  If you have enabled the required ICMP types, you won't need to configure anything.

Comment: It works with sudo and the -I option. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you allow a wider ICMP response.

```
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: These rules are for input, not output correct? They are already by default in my `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file and I still had the issue. I think I need output rules to make things work. I still canot make traceroute work though.

Comment: Have you tried sudo traceroute www.google.com?

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I also had to use the -I option (Use ICMP ECHO for tracerouting).